# Autoingestion.class has stopped creating report files

Tags: app-store-connect

A few month ago i wrote some scripts to fetch the itunes connect sales reports automatically. Today i noticed that the scripts has stopped working correctly, so i searched for the problem.

Obviously the Autoingestion Tool from Apple (Autoingestion.class) has stopped to create the expected output files...

Usage Example:
java Autoingestion *user* *pw* *vendor* Sales Daily Summary 20130401

Syntax is still correct regarding http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

The tool runs fine without any errors. Just the expected output file is missing :(.

To except problems with java - i tested the tool on different platforms with different JVM versions.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: I tested the Autoingestion tool on another platform (Debian Squeeze 64 bit / Sun JRE 64 bit 1.6.0_37-b06) and it works there. So the problem seems to be the JRE version. Is still dont understand the root cause of this, but this works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but per your own comment, I tried it on another box with an up to date JRE, I believe, and it worked. (I'd tried it on my dev box, but running it on the live box worked. Makes sense.)

Just adding, this is the output we want to see:

```
$ java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties <vendor> Sales Daily Summary 20130801
S_D_<vendor>_20130801.txt.gz
File Downloaded Successfully
```

I'm inclined to think there should *always* be output from running Autoingestion. I actually had the wrong credentials when I ran it at first, but it couldn't even tell me that, in the wrong environment.